# How to use route objects (react-router v6) for authentication to prevent hooks errors

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, redux-toolkit

I am trying to make authentication for a React JS project with react router v6, but I am getting the following error:
When I sign in:

> Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by App. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed.

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

When I sign out:

> Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by App. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed.

> Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

Here's my code:
**Routes.jsx**

```
import AddNewProductPage from "pages/AddNewProductPage"
import React from "react"
import { Navigate, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

import {
  Homepage,
  SignInPage,
  ProductListManagement,
  ProductDetailPage,
  SignUpPage,
  ProductListPage,
  ForgetPasswordPage,
  ShoppingCartPage,
} from "pages"
import AdminPage from "pages/AdminPage"
import LoadingSpinner from "components/LoadingSpinner/LoadingSpinner"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"

const DefaultComponent = () => {
  return <Navigate to={Routes.home.path} />
}

export const Routes = {
  signIn: {
    path: "/sign-in",
    element: SignInPage,
  },
  signUp: {
    path: "/sign-up",
    element: SignUpPage,
  },
  forgetPassword: {
    path: "/forget-password",
    element: ForgetPasswordPage,
  },
  admin: {
    path: "/admin",
    element: AdminPage,
    isAuth: true,
    isAdmin: true,
    index: ProductListManagement,
    routes: {
      productList: {
        path: "products",
        element: ProductListManagement,
        isAuth: true,
      },
      addProduct: {
        path: "add-product",
        element: AddNewProductPage,
        isAuth: true,
      },
      editProduct: {
        path: "edit-product/:id",
        element: AddNewProductPage,
        isAuth: true,
      },
      default: {
        path: "*",
        element: DefaultComponent,
      },
    },
  },
  shoppingCart: {
    path: "/cart",
    isAuth: true,
    element: ShoppingCartPage,
    index: ShoppingCartPage,
    routes: {
      default: {
        path: "*",
        element: ShoppingCartPage,
      },
    },
  },
  home: {
    path: "/",
    element: Homepage,
    index: ProductListPage,
    routes: {
      products: {
        path: "products",
        element: ProductListPage,
      },
      productDetail: {
        path: "products/:id",
        element: ProductDetailPage,
      },
      default: {
        path: "*",
        element: DefaultComponent,
      },
    },
  },
  default: {
    path: "*",
    element: DefaultComponent,
  },
}

export function AppLoading(props) {
  return <Route path={props.path} element={<LoadingSpinner />} />
}

export function RouteComponentWrapper(route, key) {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)
  let location = useLocation()
  if (!user.isAuth && route.isAuth)
    return (
      <Route
        key={key}
        path={route.path}
        element={
          <Navigate to={Routes.signIn.path} state={{ from: location }} />
        }
      />
    )

  if (!user.isAdmin && route.isAdmin) {
    if (user.isAuth) {
      return (
        <Route
          key={key}
          path={route.path}
          element={
            <Navigate to={Routes.home.path} state={{ from: location }} />
          }
        />
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Route
          key={key}
          path={route.path}
          element={
            <Navigate to={Routes.signIn.path} state={{ from: location }} />
          }
        />
      )
    }
  }

  return (
    <Route path={route.path} element={<route.element />} key={key}>
      {route.index ? <Route index element={<route.index />} /> : undefined}
      {route.routes ? RenderRoutes(route.routes) : undefined}
    </Route>
  )
}

export function RenderRoutes(routes) {
  return Object.values(routes).map((route, index) => {
    console.log(index, route.path)
    return RouteComponentWrapper(route, index)
  })
}
```

**userSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
  userInfo: {
    username: "",
    email: "",
  },
  token: "",
  isAuth: false,
  isAdmin: false,
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    signIn: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo.email = action.payload.userInfo.email
      state.token = action.payload.token
      state.isAuth = true
      state.isAdmin = true
    },
    signInAsAdmin: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo = action.payload.userInfo
      state.token = action.payload.token
      state.isAuth = true
      state.isAdmin = true
    },
    signOut: () => {
      //state.isAuth = false
      return initialState
    },
    forgetPassword: () => {},
  },
})

export const { signIn, signInAsAdmin, signOut, forgetPassword } =
  userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from "react"
import { Routes as RoutesDom } from "react-router-dom"
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query"
import { RenderRoutes } from "routes/Routes"
import { Routes } from "routes/Routes"

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <RoutesDom>{RenderRoutes(Routes)}</RoutesDom>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

Some `console.log` if necessary

**Sign in**

```
//First render
Routes.jsx:170 0 '/sign-in'
Routes.jsx:170 1 '/sign-up'
Routes.jsx:170 2 '/forget-password'
Routes.jsx:170 3 '/admin'
Routes.jsx:170 4 '/cart'
Routes.jsx:170 5 '/'
Routes.jsx:170 0 'products'
Routes.jsx:170 1 'products/:id'
Routes.jsx:170 2 '*'
Routes.jsx:170 6 '*'

//Second render
Routes.jsx:170 0 '/sign-in'
Routes.jsx:170 1 '/sign-up'
Routes.jsx:170 2 '/forget-password'
Routes.jsx:170 3 '/admin'
Routes.jsx:170 0 'products'
Routes.jsx:170 1 'add-product'
Routes.jsx:170 2 'edit-product/:id'
Routes.jsx:170 3 '*'
Routes.jsx:170 4 '/cart'
Routes.jsx:170 0 '*'
Routes.jsx:170 5 '/'
Error
```

**Sign out**

```
//First render
Routes.jsx:170 0 '/sign-in'
Routes.jsx:170 1 '/sign-up'
Routes.jsx:170 2 '/forget-password'
Routes.jsx:170 3 '/admin'
Routes.jsx:170 0 'products'
Routes.jsx:170 1 'add-product'
Routes.jsx:170 2 'edit-product/:id'
Routes.jsx:170 3 '*'
Routes.jsx:170 4 '/cart'
Routes.jsx:170 0 '*'
Routes.jsx:170 5 '/'
Routes.jsx:170 0 'products'
Routes.jsx:170 1 'products/:id'
Routes.jsx:170 2 '*'
Routes.jsx:170 6 '*'

//Second render
Routes.jsx:170 0 '/sign-in'
Routes.jsx:170 1 '/sign-up'
Routes.jsx:170 2 '/forget-password'
Routes.jsx:170 3 '/admin'
Routes.jsx:170 4 '/cart'
Routes.jsx:170 5 '/'
Routes.jsx:170 0 'products'
Routes.jsx:170 1 'products/:id'
Routes.jsx:170 2 '*'
Routes.jsx:170 6 '*'
Error
```

Comment: Other than the `useSelector` and `useLocation` hooks I don't see where your code uses, or abuses, React hooks. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I will do it as soon as I possibly can

Comment: Ok, you can ping me here if you like, to get my attention more quickly.

Comment: @DrewReese  This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-northcutt-21bhz). Codesandbox showed me where the problem is but I still don't know how to fix it.